# how to get next/previous post hrefs and titles in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

It's about the view of a single post. I'm trying to set the links for previous and next blogposts like this way:

```
<a class="prevpost" href="linktoprevpost" title="prev post's title">&nbsp;</a>
<a class="nextpost" href="linktonextpost" title="next post's title">&nbsp;</a>
```

where both links get an image as background by using display: block and specified width and height. The titles of the linked posts should be accessible via the title-attribute of the a-tags, so that users can see them by hovering.
I also want to restrict the linked posts on the current category. So I need to find a way to get

1. an a-tag with the href of the previous/next post
2. which is in the same category as the one currently viewed
3. without inner text because of the backgroundimage
4. with the previous/next post name in title-attribute
5. with a custom css-class

The category matching needs to be only the first level because I divided my page into 3 main categories. I'm using

```
$a = get_the_category(get_the_ID());
$cat = $a[0]->name;
```

for getting the first category's name and setting it as additional body-class in header.php. Maybe I could reuse that?

I also found out that using previous_post_link() and next_post_link() like this way

```
next_post_link('%link', '', TRUE);
```

gives me the posts of the same category without inner content, so 1 & 2 & 3 would be solved. But it seems, to get 4 & 5 too I'll need another way.

Using Wordpress Version 3.4.1.

Comment: See also http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57831/get-the-prev-next-page-links-only-not-title-a-etc

Comment: It's about previous page, not post, and I can't find a match of my 5-point-listing above.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

No need for functions and filters all you need to do is to use `get_adjacent_post` instead of `next_post_link` and `prev_post_link`, Note that `get_adjacent_post` is used to get previous and next post, you can read about it [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_adjacent_post)
To get previous post and it's title attribute use this

```
$prev_post = get_adjacent_post(false, '', true);
if(!empty($prev_post)) {
echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($prev_post->ID) . '" title="' . $prev_post->post_title . '">' . $prev_post->post_title . '</a>'; }
```

To get next post and it's title attribute use this

```
$next_post = get_adjacent_post(false, '', false);
if(!empty($next_post)) {
echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($next_post->ID) . '" title="' . $next_post->post_title . '">' . $next_post->post_title . '</a>'; }
```

Comment: I use it but for the next post it shows the current post ID and for the previous it shows 3 or 4 times Id post for previous posts

Comment: I just love this solution, it is work for me. Thanks a lot - @Christina

Answer (score 1):

Got it.

Now this is my code:

```
$p = get_adjacent_post(1, '', 1);
if(!empty($p)) echo '<a class="prevpost" href="'.$p->guid.'" title="'.$p->post_title.'">&nbsp</a>';
$n = get_adjacent_post(1, '', 0);
if(!empty($n)) echo '<a class="nextpost" href="'.$n->guid.'" title="'.$n->post_title.'">&nbsp</a>';
```

The function returns an object of the prev/next post which I can use for generating my links. The first parameter is for restricting the post on the same cat.
I searched in wordpress codex a few times yesterday but didn't come across this function, now stumled upon it by accident.

If someone has a better/simpler/faster method please post to get an accepted answer.

Comment: do not use the guid as the post link, it does not get updated when post slugs change or if you move to a new domain, etc. use `get_permalink($post->ID)` instead, as that will always give you the correct link.

Answer (score 0):

step 1 : you just need to add this function below in function.php

```
// its to ssolve single page next and previous liinks
# get_adjacent_post( $in_same_cat = false, $excluded_categories = '', $previous = true )
function echo_next_previous_post_link($fmg_name="link" ,$selector="next")
{  

if ($selector=="next") {
    $next_post_obj  = get_adjacent_post( '', '', false );
    $next_post_ID   = isset( $next_post_obj->ID ) ? $next_post_obj->ID : '';
    $next_post_link     = get_permalink( $next_post_ID );
    $next_post_title = get_the_title($next_post_ID);
    if ($fmg_name=="link") {
        echo $next_post_link ;
    }
    else {
        echo $next_post_title ;
    }
}
else {
    $previous_post_obj  = get_adjacent_post( '', '', true );
    $previous_post_ID   = isset( $previous_post_obj->ID ) ? $previous_post_obj->ID : '';
    $previous_post_link     = get_permalink( $previous_post_ID );
    $previous_post_title = get_the_title($previous_post_ID);
    if ($fmg_name=="link") {
        echo $previous_post_link ;
    }
    else {
        echo $previous_post_title ;
    }
}

}
```

Step 2 : now you can print post url and title in any page you want

```
<a href="<?php echo_next_previous_post_link("link","next"); ?>"><?php echo_next_previous_post_link("title","next"); ?></a>                            

<a href="<?php echo_next_previous_post_link("link","previous"); ?>"><?php echo_next_previous_post_link("title","previous"); ?></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous code didn't work for me.
I came to the following

```html
<?php 
  $prev = get_adjacent_post(true,'',true); 
  $next = get_adjacent_post(true,'',false);
?>
      
<div>
  <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($prev->ID);?>">Previous</a>
  <p><?php echo get_the_title($prev->ID );?></p>
</div>
                                  
<div>
  <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($next->ID);?>">Next</a>
  <p><?php echo get_the_title($next->ID );?></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -5):

```
<?
echo '<a href="'.get_permalink( get_the_ID()-1 ).'" title="'.get_the_title( get_the_ID()-1 ).'">Previous</a>'; 
echo '<a href="'.get_permalink( get_the_ID()+1 ).'" title="'.get_the_title( get_the_ID()-1 ).'">Next</a>';

?>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I guess I can't go straight along the post IDs if I want to restrict the linked posts on the main current category. It could be possible that the next ID would return a post of another category.

Comment: Not easily. You can use if statements to see if there is a next page or if there is a previous page

Comment: adding and subtracting 1 from the ID is definitely not a reliable way to get the next and previous posts.