# How to include title attribute in this PHP Code

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<div class="alignleft">
<?php previous_post('&laquo; &laquo; %', 'Previous Post ', 'no'); ?>
</div>
<div class="alignright">
<?php next_post('% &raquo; &raquo; ', 'Next Post ', 'no'); ?>
</div>
```

Hi I have pasted the wordpress Older and Newer Post code,
I want to show the post title, when user hover on those link.
How to include...

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11383074/22470) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11379623/22470) answer.

Both times they use Wordpress functions to receive the title and build the link manually.

And according to [this question and answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57831/get-the-prev-next-page-links-only-not-title-a-etc) there is a function called [`get_previous_posts_page_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_previous_posts_link).