# Wordpress - Hiding 'Next' article link on latest post and 'Prev' article link on the oldest post

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the previous_post_link & next_post_link to display links to next & prev articles on a post single page. This works fine and the code I'm using is like this:

```
<div class="previous-article">
    <h4>Previous Article</h4>
    <?php previous_post_link('%link'); ?>
</div>

<div class="next-article">
    <h4>Next Article</h4>
    <?php next_post_link('%link'); ?>
</div>
```

Is there a statement I can use to hide / not display the 'Next' article link on the latest blog post because there is no 'next' so it display a blank entry (meaning that I can also hide the h4 headings I have in place) e.g.

[image]

So it looks like this:

[image]

And visa versa for the oldest post showing the 'Previous' article. Another solution would be to incorporate the heading into the php previous_post_link / next_post_link code. Maybe add class 'latest', 'oldest' to the body tag and I can hide using css. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I should have searched better. For anyone else looking here is the solution to this [how to get next/previous post hrefs and titles in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11379549/how-to-get-next-previous-post-hrefs-and-titles-in-wordpress)